# kendo UI Grid MVC initial page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI Grid. Is there a way to start the grid at a different page than the first page?
i want to set initial page number to '3' every time i open the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to set the **AutoBind** property of the Grid to **false** and when the document ready event occurs use the **page** method of the **dataSource** (which is actually what the **pager.page** invokes).

```
$('#MyGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.page(3);
```

The **Data** function which you used is intended for slightly different purposes :)

Comment: thanks @Pechka! I ended up doing what you said, only slightly different.
I set AutoBind to false and then i used the following code - 
                $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.query({ page: 3, pageSize: myGrid.pager.pageSize() }); 
It basically does the same thing but with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't working at all doing it like this on initial page load: $('#MyGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.page(3);  Only  $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.query({ page: 3, pageSize: myGrid.pager.pageSize() }); actually works in the initial page load scenario.  (I use datasource.page() other places in my application, but never to set the initial page.)

Answer (score 2):

I use an ajax datasource, and I needed to do:

1. Set the AutoBind to false
2. Set the total records in the data source
3. Call by javascript the page() method of the data source

Here is a fragment of my view (I use razor):
Notes: In the action I set two values in the ViewBag:

- **ViewBag.InitialPage:** Initial page to show
- **ViewBag.Total:** Total record count

.

```
@{
    int initialPage = (int)ViewBag.InitialPage;
    int totalPages = (int)ViewBag.Total / 20;
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourModelClass>
    ()
    .Name("gridMain")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        //Todo: Add your columns
    })
    .Pageable(p => p.Refresh(true).Info(true).Input(true).ButtonCount(6).Numeric(true))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("YourAction", "YourController"))
        .Total(ViewBag.Total) //Set the total record count
    )
    .AutoBind(false)        
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var initialPage = @initialPage;
        $('#gridMain').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.page(initialPage);
    })
</script>
```